# How to get nested elements from a JSON Object?

Tags: python, json

JSON file I have has following data:

```
{
    "P1":{
        "L1":{
            "crn":"1"
        },
        "L2":{
            "crn":"100"
        }
        
    },
    "P2":{
        "L3":{
            "crn":"xx"
        },
        "L4":{
            "crn":"xxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get `[L1,L2,L3,L4]` efficiently?
I can load the data and loop over `dict.values()`.

Is there any better, efficient way?

Comment: why do you need to loop when you know the value of all the keys?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Do you want the CRNs, or the names of the keys `L1`, `L2`, ... ?

Comment: Say hypothetically P1 and P2 are two buildings. L1-L4 are rooms in the building. My lead asks me to provide them a list of all rooms in all buildings. That's all. I am just trying to see if there's an efficient method that can do the work without loops.

Comment: You're going to have to iterate over the data somehow, so even if there is no loop, you're going to have some sort of iteration structure.

Comment: @helloworld Do you really think that when you type  P2.L3.crn a compiler can select it immediately using some magic  from hundreds another objects? It generates  a loop that is going through all elements and selects what is needed. What is wrong if you create your own loop? it will be more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to extract the room numbers, then use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten everything into a one-dimensional list:

```py
import json
from itertools import chain

with open('input.json') as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)
    # Prints ['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4']
    print(list(chain.from_iterable(value.keys() for value in data.values())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using list comprehension and flattening in a single line (assuming your json is saved to a dictionary called `buildings`):

```
>>> [item for sublist in buildings.values() for item in sublist]
['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4']
```